# verb + into VS noun+ into

Tags: meaning, grammar, word-usage, grammaticality

1. I walked right into a mob of maybe 50 young white guys.
2. A short walk into a forest-like part of the farm leads to the base of a tree where Ms Chiliza's remains were discovered.

I am familiar with the use of "into" with verbs like the example number 1. Some sort of motion is related here.

But what's the meaning of "into" in the second example?  Is it possible to say :

A short walk to a forest like part of the farm........?

Another example I can give is : Australia has also been conducting a probe into the scandal.

Here is it possible to use "to" instead of "into" with prob?

Please explain where I can use "into" with a noun.

Comment: Why do you think you can say "I walked into the forest", but you cannot say "I took a walk into the forest"? Did you think some rule forbids it?

Comment: @Michael,  Exactly. I thought there is no motion when "into" is used with a noun. Thus, we can't use "into" with a noun.

Comment: I asked you why you believed there is such a rule. THERE IS NOT. You can use into with a verb, e.g. look into, walk into, enquire into, etc. You CAN ALSO use 'into' with a noun, e.g. take a look into, take a walk into, start an enquiry into, etc. The motion can be figurative or metaphorical.

Comment: @Michael Harvey,  What about "conducting a prob into vs "conducting a prob to "?

Comment: Do you a mean a **probe**?

Comment: @Michael Hervey, sorry spelling mistake. It's "probe".

Comment: Probing a thing, or probing into a thing, or starting/conducting/finishing a probe into a thing.

Answer (score -1):

Both "a walk to a forest" and "a walk into a forest" are grammatically correct, but they mean different things. The former means a walk that brings one to the edge of a forest; the latter means a walk that goes into the interior of the forest.

Comment: @Andreas_Blass,  Like that, can we say "conducting a probe to the scandal?

Comment: @techiez I don't see how to assign any meaning to "probe to the scandal", so if I read that phrase I"d assume "to" was a mistake and "into" was meant.